# How to do a sum of sums of the square of sum of sums?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sum of sums that I want to speed up. In one case it is:

S_{x,y,k,l} Fu_{ku} Fv_{lv} Fx_{kx} Fy_{ly}

In the other case it is:

S_{x,y} ( S_{k,l} Fu_{ku} Fv_{lv} Fx_{kx} Fy_{ly} )^2

*Note: S_{indices}: is the sum over those indices*

The first case I have figured out how to do using numpy's `einsum` and it results in an amazing speedup ~ x160.

Also, I have thought of trying to expand the square but won't that be a killer as I would need to sum over x,y,k,l,k,l instead of x,y,k,l?

Here is an implementation that demonstrates the difference and the solution I have with `einsum`.

```
Nx = 3
Ny = 4
Nk = 5
Nl = 6
Nu = 7
Nv = 8
Fx = np.random.rand(Nx, Nk)
Fy = np.random.rand(Ny, Nl)
Fu = np.random.rand(Nu, Nk)
Fv = np.random.rand(Nv, Nl)
P = np.random.rand(Nx, Ny)
B = np.random.rand(Nk, Nl)
I1 = np.zeros([Nu, Nv])
I2 = np.zeros([Nu, Nv])
t = time.time()
for iu in range(Nu):
    for iv in range(Nv):
        for ix in range(Nx):
            for iy in range(Ny):
                S = 0.
                for ik in range(Nk):
                    for il in range(Nl):
                        S += Fu[iu,ik]*Fv[iv,il]*Fx[ix,ik]*Fy[iy,il]*P[ix,iy]*B[ik,il]
                I1[iu, iv] += S
                I2[iu, iv] += S**2.
print time.time() - t; t = time.time()
# 0.0787379741669
I1_ = np.einsum('uk, vl, xk, yl, xy, kl->uv', Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
print time.time() - t
# 0.00049090385437
print np.allclose(I1_, I1)
# True
# Solution by expanding the square (not ideal)
t = time.time()
I2_ = np.einsum('uk,vl,xk,yl,um,vn,xm,yn,kl,mn,xy->uv', Fu,Fv,Fx,Fy,Fu,Fv,Fx,Fy,B,B,P**2)
print time.time() - t
# 0.0226809978485 <- faster than for loop but still much slower than I1_ einsum
print np.allclose(I2_, I2)
# True
```

As shown I've managed to do I1_ with I've figured out how to do the above with `einsum` for `I1`.

**EDIT:**

I added how to do `I2_` by expanding the square but the speed up is a bit disappointing and to be expected... ~x3.47 speedup compared to ~x160

**EDIT2:**

The speedups don't seem to be consistent, I had gotten before a x40 and an x1.2 but now get different numbers. Either way the difference and the question remain.

**EDIT3:**
I tried to simplify the sum I'm actually after but messed up and the sum above allows for the excellent answer provided by @user5402.

I've edited the code above to demonstrate the sum which is below:

I1 = S_{x,y,k,l} Fu_{ku} Fv_{lv} Fx_{kx} Fy_{ly} P_{xy} B_{kl}

I2 = S_{x,y} ( S_{k,l} Fu_{ku} Fv_{lv} Fx_{kx} Fy_{ly} P_{xy} B_{kl} )^2

Comment: there is some overhead getting into C land ... try it with bigger arrays ... I think you will see speed up proportional to the size of the dataset

Comment: @SlaterTyranus for which part? that is a JIT compiler correct? I would use it for a function which does the for loops?

Comment: @JoranBeasley You're referring to the I2_ expression? I was hoping there would be a way to avoid the expansion as that increases my dimensionality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start a new answer since the problem has changed.

Try this:

```
E = np.einsum('uk, vl, xk, yl, xy, kl->uvxy', Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
E1 = np.einsum('uvxy->uv', E)
E2 = np.einsum('uvxy->uv', np.square(E))
```

I've found it runs just as fast as the time for I1_.

Here is my test code: http://pastebin.com/ufwy7cLy

Comment: hm... Yeah this would work. thank you, I've got a follow up but will post in a new question. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: looking forward to it ;-)

Comment: so kind of figured it out but please comment / answer if you have a better response! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431141/how-to-sum-of-squares-of-sum-with-memory-limitations/27431142#27431142

Answer (score 4):

(Update: Jump to the end to see the result expressed as a couple of matrix multiplications.)

I think you can greatly simplify the computation by using the identity:

[image]

For instance,

```
S_{k,l} Fu_{ku} Fv_{lv} Fx_{kx} Fy_{ly}
  = S_{k,l} Fu_{ku} Fx_{kx} Fv_{lv} Fy_{ly}            -- rearrange the factors
            \___ A ____/    \___ B ____/
  = ( S_k Fu_{ku} Fx_{kx} ) * ( S_l Fv_{lv} Fy_{ly} )  -- from the identity
  =   A_{ux}                * B_{vy}
```

where `A_{ux}` only depends on `u` and `x` and `B_{vy}` only depends on `v` and `y`.

For the square sum, we have:

```
S_k [ S_l Fu_{ku} Fv_{lv} Fx_{kx} Fy_{ly} ]^2
  = S_k Fu_{ku} Fx_{kx} * [ S_l Fv_{lv} Fy_{ly} ]^2
  = S_k Fu_{ku} Fx_{kx} * B_{vy}^2                 -- B is from the above calc.
  = B_{vy}^2 * S_k Fu_{ku} Fx_{kx}                 -- B_vy is free of k
  = B_{vy}^2 * A_{ux}                              -- A is from the above calc.
```

Similar reductions occur when continuing the sum over `x` and `y`:

```
S_{xy} A_{ux} * B_{vy}
  = S_x A_{ux} * S_y B_{vy}                        -- from the identity
  =  C_u       *    D_v
```

And then finally summing over `u` and `v`:

```
S_{uv} C_u D_v = (S_u C_u) * (S_v D_v)             -- from the identity
```

Hope this helps.

Update: I just realized that perhaps for the square sum you wanted to compute
`[ S_k S_l ... ]^2` in which case you can proceed like this:

```
[ S_k  S_l Fu_{ku} Fv_{lv} Fx_{kx} Fy_{ly} ]^2
  =  [ A_{ux}                * B_{vy} ]^2
  =  A_{ux}^2 * B_{vy}^2
```

So when we sum over the over variables we get:

```
S_{uvxy} A_{ux}^2 B_{vy}^2
  = S_{uv} ( S_{xy}  A_{ux}^2 B_{vy}^2 )
  = S_{uv} ( S_x A_{ux}^2 ) * ( S_y B_{vy}^2 )     -- from the identity
  = S_{uv}     C_u          *      D_v
  = (S_u C_u) * (S_v D_v)                          -- from the identity
```

Update 2: This does boil down to just a few matrix multiplications.

The definitions of A and B:

```
A_{uv} = S_k Fu_{ku} Fx_{kx}
B_{vy} = S_l Fv_{lv} Fy_{ly}
```

may also be written in matrix form as:

```
A = (transpose Fu) . Fx             -- . = matrix multiplication
B = (transpose Fv) . Fy
```

and the definition of C and D:

```
C_u = S_x A_{ux}
D_v = S_y B_{vy}
```

we see that the vector C is just the row sums of A and the vector D is just the row sums of B. Since the answer for the entire summation (not squared) is:

```
total = (S_u C_u) * (S_v D_v)
```

we see that the total is just the sum of all of the matrix elements of A times the sum of all of the matrix elements of B.

Here is the numpy code:

```
from numpy import *
# ... set up Fx, Fv, Fu, Fy as above...

A = Fx.dot(Fu.transpose())
B = Fv.dot(Fy.transpose())
sum1 = sum(A) * sum(B)

A2 = square(A)
B2 = square(B)
sum2 = sum(A2) * sum(B2)

print "sum of terms:", sum1
print "sum of squares of terms:", sum2
```

Comment: I've edited the question, so that this isn't possible, I had tried to simplify my problem for posting purposes but then it allowed for this answer. Sorry about that, upvoted though for catching me out!