# How to sum of squares of sum with memory limitations?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

This is a follow up of this question:

[How to do a sum of sums of the square of sum of sums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415681/how-to-do-a-sum-of-sums-of-the-square-of-sum-of-sums/27429713?noredirect=1#comment43302700_27429713)

Where I was asking for help to use einsum (to achieve a great speed increase) and got a great answer.

I also got a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415681/how-to-do-a-sum-of-sums-of-the-square-of-sum-of-sums/27429713?noredirect=1#comment43275638_27415681) to use `numba`. I've gone and tried both and it seems that after a certain point the speed increase in `numba` is much better.

So how do you speed it up without running into memory issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below presents the 3 different methods to do the simple sum of sums and 4 different methods to do the sum of squares.

sum of sums 3 methods - for loop, JIT for loops, einsum (none run into memory problems)

sum of square of sums 4 methods - for loop, JIT for loops, expanded einsum, intermediate einsum

Here the first three don't run into memory problems and the for loop and the expanded einsum run into speed problems. This leaves the JIT solution seeming the best.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from numba import jit

def fun1(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B):
    Nu = Fu.shape[0]
    Nv = Fv.shape[0]
    Nx = Fx.shape[0]
    Ny = Fy.shape[0]
    Nk = Fu.shape[1]
    Nl = Fv.shape[1]
    I1 = np.zeros([Nu, Nv])
    for iu in range(Nu):
        for iv in range(Nv):
            for ix in range(Nx):
                for iy in range(Ny):
                    S = 0.
                    for ik in range(Nk):
                        for il in range(Nl):
                            S += Fu[iu,ik]*Fv[iv,il]*Fx[ix,ik]*Fy[iy,il]*P[ix,iy]*B[ik,il]
                    I1[iu, iv] += S
    return I1

def fun2(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B):
    Nu = Fu.shape[0]
    Nv = Fv.shape[0]
    Nx = Fx.shape[0]
    Ny = Fy.shape[0]
    Nk = Fu.shape[1]
    Nl = Fv.shape[1]
    I2 = np.zeros([Nu, Nv])
    for iu in range(Nu):
        for iv in range(Nv):
            for ix in range(Nx):
                for iy in range(Ny):
                    S = 0.
                    for ik in range(Nk):
                        for il in range(Nl):
                            S += Fu[iu,ik]*Fv[iv,il]*Fx[ix,ik]*Fy[iy,il]*P[ix,iy]*B[ik,il]
                    I2[iu, iv] += S**2.
    return I2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Nx = 30
    Ny = 40
    Nk = 50
    Nl = 60
    Nu = 70
    Nv = 8
    Fx = np.random.rand(Nx, Nk)
    Fy = np.random.rand(Ny, Nl)
    Fu = np.random.rand(Nu, Nk)
    Fv = np.random.rand(Nv, Nl)
    P = np.random.rand(Nx, Ny)
    B = np.random.rand(Nk, Nl)
    fjit1 = jit(fun1)
    fjit2 = jit(fun2)

    # For loop - becomes too slow so commented out
    # t = time.time()
    # I1 = fun1(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
    # print 'fun1    :', time.time() - t

    # JIT compiled for loop - After a certain point beats einsum
    t = time.time()
    I1jit = fjit1(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
    print 'jit1    :', time.time() - t

    # einsum great solution when no squaring is needed
    t = time.time()
    I1_ = np.einsum('uk, vl, xk, yl, xy, kl->uv', Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
    print '1 einsum:', time.time() - t

    # For loop - becomes too slow so commented out
    # t = time.time()
    # I2 = fun2(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
    # print 'fun2    :', time.time() - t

    # JIT compiled for loop - After a certain point beats einsum
    t = time.time()
    I2jit = fjit2(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
    print 'jit2    :', time.time() - t

    # Expanded einsum - As the size increases becomes very very slow
    # t = time.time()
    # I2_ = np.einsum('uk,vl,xk,yl,um,vn,xm,yn,kl,mn,xy->uv', Fu,Fv,Fx,Fy,Fu,Fv,Fx,Fy,B,B,P**2)
    # print '2 einsum:', time.time() - t

    # Intermediate einsum - As the sizes increase memory can become an issue
    t = time.time()
    temp = np.einsum('uk, vl, xk, yl, xy, kl->uvxy', Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B)
    I2__ = np.einsum('uvxy->uv', np.square(temp))
    print '2 einsum:', time.time() - t

    # print 'I1 == I1_   :', np.allclose(I1, I1_)
    print 'I1_ == Ijit1_:', np.allclose(I1_, I1jit)
    # print 'I2 == I2_   :', np.allclose(I2, I2_)
    print 'I2_ == Ijit2_:', np.allclose(I2__, I2jit)
```

Comment:
Please feel free to edit / improve this answer. It would be nice if someone had any suggestions with regards to making this parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You could sum over one index first and then continue the multiplication. I have also tried versions with numexpr thrown in to the last multiplication and reduction operations but it doesn't seem to help too much.

```
def fun3(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B):
    P = P[None, None, ...]
    Fu = Fu[:, None, None, None, :]
    Fx = Fx[None, None, :, None, :]
    Fv = Fv[:, None, None, :]
    Fy = Fy[None, :, None, :]
    B = B[None, None, ...]
    return np.sum((P*np.sum(Fu*Fx*np.sum(Fv*Fy*B, axis=-1)[None, :, None, :, :], axis=-1))**2, axis=(2, 3))
```

It's much faster on my computer:

jit2    : 7.06 s

fun3: 0.144 s

Edit: Minor improvement - multiply first then square.

Edit2:
Leveraging what each does best (numexpr - multiplication, numpy - dot/tensordot, summation) you can still improve over the fun3 more than 20 times.

```
def fun4(Fu, Fv, Fx, Fy, P, B):
    P = P[None, None, ...]
    Fu = Fu[:, None, :]
    Fx = Fx[None, ...]
    Fy = Fy[:, None, :]
    B = B[None, ...]
    s = ne.evaluate('Fu*Fx')
    r = np.tensordot(Fv, ne.evaluate('Fy*B'), axes=(1, 2))
    I = np.tensordot(s, r, axes=(2, 2)).swapaxes(1, 2)
    r = ne.evaluate('(P*I)**2')
    r = np.sum(r, axis=(2, 3))
    return r
```

fun4: 0.007 s

Moreover, since fun8 is not that memory hungry anymore (due to the smart tensordot) you can multiply much bigger arrays and see it use multiple cores.

Comment: yeah I think the main reason for your speedup is the fact that you're storing intermediate results and then summing over those. That's what I ended up doing but with jit as I think it will be faster. I might post later if I have time how that code would look like. Also, the final thing to note is that if you're doing it this way you might as well use `numexpr`. for example replace `np.sum(Fv*Fy*B, axis=-1)` with `ne.execute('sum(Fv*Fy*B,3)')` this way it doesn't store the intermediate result and is multithreaded

Comment: That's what I tried and mentioned. It actually doesn't help. And I don't think that the main reason for the speedup is creating intermediate arrays. The main speedup I believe is coming from the summation before creating one big array. Hence I would say it is hidden in the reduction before multiplication.

Comment: ok yeah sorry about that. The main thing that suprises me is that multiple cores don't change the result. I have 16 which is why it may be more significant. Also, as far as identifying the source of the speedup I think we meant the same thing only I phrased it a bit poorly. The simplest way to explain is that (AB)X is slower than A(BX) where A is: m x n, B: n x l and X is l x 1