# Is it possible to sum over multiple axis in numexpr?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numexpr

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
import numexpr as ne

a = np.random.rand(10, 1)
b = np.random.rand(1, 10)
ne.NumExpr('sum(sum(a*b, 1), 0)').run(a, b) # <- error: reduction operations must occur last
ne.NumExpr('sum(a*b, [1, 0])').run(a, b) # <- error: ValueError: cannot encode axis
```

This returns with the error documented here:

https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide#supported-reduction-operations

I was wondering if there is a workaround that I haven't thought of.

**EDIT**

To answer some comments:

This is a simpler example than the actual one I'm interested in. A more complete example exists here:

[How to sum of squares of sum with memory limitations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431141/how-to-sum-of-squares-of-sum-with-memory-limitations)

and here:

[How to do a sum of sums of the square of sum of sums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415681/how-to-do-a-sum-of-sums-of-the-square-of-sum-of-sums)

I don't expect you to read through those questions.

The primary reason I was interested in a `numexpr` implementation is that it offers easy support for multithreading compared to anything else I've seen, and the reduction operators reduce the need for memory storage which at times is crucial in my case.

I hope this clears a few things up.

Comment: You can of course reshape the result of the multiplication but I doubt it will be faster than np.sum over two axes. But it might be possible to rewrite your computation somehow if you'll explain in more detail what you want.

Comment: Reshaping in what sense? I have a feeling such a solution would increase memory requirements.

Comment: Something like (a*b).reshape(a.shape[0]*b.shape[1]).sum(). It depends what is your real goal. You can also get the same result by the following: np.sum(a)*np.sum(b). It is not of much help with the numexpr issue but on the other hand it does what you want.

Comment: I edited the question to maybe address the motivation for the question.

Comment: I have added an answer to the original question of yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum over multiple axes using numexpr as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

a = np.random.rand(10, 1)
b = np.random.rand(1, 10)
ne.evaluate('sum(x, 0)', {'x': ne.evaluate('sum(a*b, 1)')})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using two expressions?

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

a = np.random.rand(10, 1)
b = np.random.rand(1, 10)
ab = ne.evaluate('sum(a*b, 0)') # Calculates sum over first axis
print ne.evaluate('sum(ab, 0)') # <- Calculates sum over summed axis
```

I am not sure if this is a solution for you but this would avoid the limited usage of functions/sums in numexpr.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that `ab` will have to be stored in memory which isn't always possible in my case.